# Choosing a suitable multi-media builder software

Tags: multimedia

Hi foks
I need a software but I am not a multimedia builder I am a .net developer I want to choose a software to build my first multi-media application I have to do something with this software :

1- it must be portable between different Windows operation
2- it would be independent I mean I don't want to install other software before it.
3- it must run at the autorun for CD
4- I need search ability for some values in the information
5- I don't want someone copy my information easily.
6- The information are videos and rich text
7- it has ability to change on specific screen resolution

Please guide me which softwares I mean a software to build this application are suitable for me I need something to build more easy not very complex but I need beautifull User Interface at the result.

Comment: Information are static and there is no update progress it runs on cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to develop a multimedia distribution which has videos and text for the end user. That's very similar to a tutorial or training CD or DVD. There are many ways to develop this sort of content, but perhaps the easiest (although not particularly .NET-related) would be a web-based site stored on disc.

Design the product using HTML, CSS, and your preferred video format for web. (Silverlight, Flash, Quicktime...)

To address your points:

1. Web-based data is extremely portable, not just between Windows installations but across platforms and browsers.
2. It would be free from dependencies for the most part, assuming the user has a web browser with applicable add-ons to view the video content (such as a Flash or Silverlight plug-in).
3. You can use a text editor to create an `autorun.inf` file which will automatically load the main file (usually index.html).
4. The user can use the browser search functionality to easily find keywords in the pages. If you need the ability to search the entire contents of the multimedia package, that will add a small amount of complication.
5. The downside to a web-based product is that the files are plain text and anyone can easily copy the data. The question I have is whether you want to try and prevent copying of the entire product (say, as a CD) or just the information it displays?
6. There shouldn't be any problems displaying videos and rich text in a web environment, provided you've converted them to a format that is compatible with the intended distribution. (For example, if your audience uses Windows and you know they will have a Flash plugin, then a Flash-based video format would be ideal.)
7. Assuming that you mean reflow by "change on specific screen resolution," this was one of the main reasons I thought of web-based media. The browser of course be capable of displaying content with appropriate resizing capability just as most web sites which are crafted with consideration for multiple screen sizes. This is simply a matter of using appropriate CSS to ensure that elements appear just as logical on a widescreen, high-resolution monitor as they do on the lowest expected resolution screen.

To build a multimedia site, consider Adobe's products such as DreamWeaver, Photoshop, Flash, Fireworks, etc. (http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/web/whatsnew/)

If you would prefer to develop an application using .NET Framework, instead you may want to consider Windows Presentation Foundation (http://windowsclient.net/wpf/white-papers/when-to-adopt-wpf.aspx) however there may be prerequisites depending on how you build the application.

Comment: No I mean the structure of information and my own information not cd, CD could be copied no problem but I don't want someone can make another CD with his/her name but with my information.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is some sort of obfuscation or encryption on the actual data you want to prevent changes on. Maybe you should ask a separate question about how best to disallow editing of your content (or at least make it difficult) since the question here is fairly broad.

Answer (score 2):

You should try medichance's multimedia builder. It is doing the exact things you described.

http://www.mediachance.com/mmb/